# Cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a cookie "A" set at a domain at bc.test.com(all urls are changed to protect company info).

I also have a cookie "B" set at a domain of .test.com.

I also have a Javascript file hosted at bc.test.com/_include.

Now, in my host file, I have setting to point bc.test.com to a development server.

But now, when I try reading cookie "A" using document.cookie, I am not able to access the cookie.  I can however read cookie "B".  I though as long as the cookie is set at the same level domain, I should be able to read it - right?

Seems to be a very simple problem, yet I am confounded by how it's currently working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a cookie, you need:

- Have the same subdomain (ok, all in test.com)
- Have the same location ("folder")

Check this first of all.

---

**EDIT**

Ex: 
If your you have `bc.test.com/index.php` you can read cookies in all paths in `bc.test.com`. But if you have `bc.test.com/includes/index.php`, you can read only cookies from folder `include`.

Look this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for more information about cookie path.

> The path gives you the chance to
>   specify a directory where the cookie
>   is active. So if you want the cookie
>   to be only sent to pages in the
>   directory cgi-bin, set the path to
>   /cgi-bin. Usually the path is set to
>   /, which means the cookie is valid
>   throughout the entire domain.

Comment: are you saying a file that is stored in _include/script.js won't be able to read a cookie for a file that is in test/help.js although they're set to the same domain?

Comment: No. I'm saying that the page that reads the cookie must be in the same domain. A'll Edit my answer.